# Sessions Are not Working

Tags: php

hi i want to start a session of user but i am unable to do that. i have see examples of it also but my problem is still the same. i am getting this error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /home/a2277283/public_html/scripts/login.php on line 11
```

here is my code

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    include 'db.php';
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        echo $email = $_POST['user_email'];
        $sql = "select * from user where `user_email` = '$email'";
        if (mysql_query($sql)) {
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            echo "$_SESSION['email']";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: just `echo $_SESSION['email'];` without double quotes

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is:

```
echo "$_SESSION['email']";
```

Use without quotes like:

```
echo $_SESSION['email'];
```

or

```
echo "$_SESSION[email]";
```

or

```
echo "{$_SESSION['email']}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Echo the session variable like this: `echo "{$_SESSION['email']}";` as described at the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)